# how to return response of axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

hello im kinda of a newbie to axios
how can i return response.data to the getOrderDetails function ?
thanks !

```
function getOrderDetails(orderid) {
  var axios = require("axios").default;

  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https//example.com'+orderid,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: '*secret api key*'
    }
  };

  axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
      // return this ^^^^^^
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: `return axios.request(options).then(res => res.data)`

Comment: In your example if you simply `return response.dada;` then the value of `response.data` will be the fulfilled result of the Promise object.

Comment: when i try this :return axios.request(options).then(res => res.data) , it gives me a :Promise { <pending> }

Comment: @mesharialzahrani: That is correct and expected behavior.  It's an asynchronous operation and it results in a Promise.  You would either `await` the Promise or append a `.then()` callback to it.